# How to get parent of Tree(List)View Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

i'm currently working on a project which shall display some date in a hierarchical way. I'm using a Tree(List)View (the one from Ricciolo) which has 3 hierarchical levels. The ItemsSource of the TLV is a List.

```
1st level = typeof(Game)
2nd level = typeof(Partner)
3rd level = typeof(Channel)
```

Everything is being displayed fine but now I have a problem. I want to start an edit mode for selected items, but therefore it is necessary to find out if and which parents the selected item has.
I already tried the following approach:

```
TreeViewItem myItem = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
if ( myItem != null ) {
    ItemsControl parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer( myItem );
    if ( parent != null ) {
    //Put your logic here.
    }
}
```

The problem here is, no matter which item I select, "myItem" will always be null.

Can somebody please point me into the right direction ?

Thx in advance, Greetings

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using the MVVM pattern in your application. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) for a good introduction, specifically in the case of tree views.

Currently, codeproject seems to have a problem. You can access the article in the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aBbgWYEt9ogcJ%3awww.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx+MVVM+TreeView&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which event you handle (MouseButtonDown?) the `e.OriginalSource` very likely contains the control within the `TreeViewItem` which raised the event (probably a `TextBlock`). You might have to walk up the VisualTree a bit using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to find the enclosing container (TreeViewItem).

Answer (score 0):

You use a safe-cast using `as` so `e.OriginalSource` is not a `TreeViewItem`, set a breakpoint and use the debugger and see what it is.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. e.OriginalSource must be one of three possibilities. Game, Partner or Channel and it is no problem to find that out. I don't want to know, which item is currently selected, but which is the parent of the current selected item.

Comment: What is your `sender`? Shouldn't that be a control related to the visual representation?

Comment: The **sender** is my TreeListView Control. My Problem is that i don't know, how to "walk up" the visual tree, because they are using Dependency Objects as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the parent using VisualTreeHelper.

Comment: I must be to stupid. I'm trying the following:    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Name1);    Name1 would be of type "Partner" or "channel". But the "GetParent"-method needs a dependency object as a parameter. How to solve this ?

Comment: you can pass your treeviewitem

Comment: if i try: DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( _myTreeView.SelectedItem ); ... it doesn't work. I get the following Message: _The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(System.Windows.DependencyObject)-Method has some invalid arguments_.

Comment: TreeViewItem myItem = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem; you can pass myitem... or you can typecaste your object into Treeviewitem